# .getValues cannot read Custom Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to create automated reports with Google Apps Script for an internal client. Straight forward: retrive data, manipulate data, some if tests, and print data in a new format.

My problem is, the source of the data uses a custom function (also designed by me, for date calculation) that is pretty complex, and it is essential for the client, and, apparently, I cannot retrieve the data with the method .getValues from custom functions.

This is the error I get:

```
9:42:41 AM  Error  Exception: Cannot convert 'function () { [native code] }' to int.
ARROBA  @ Scripts Automáticos.gs:5
```

Is this a real problem in GAS, and is there any workaround this? Or, better, have I coded something wrong? I tried indirect references (like instead of getting the data directly from the custom function, getting it from other cells that referenced that data) but it didn't work.

Here is the line where the problem occurs:

```
var data = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow, ss.getLastColumn).getValues
```

Here is on example of codes that do not work:

```
function ARROBA() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById([ID]).getSheetByName([sheet])

  var data = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow, ss.getLastColumn).getValues

  var today = new Date()

  var x
  var y

  for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    if (data[x][34] == "Sim") {
      ss.getRange(x+2,7).setValue(data[x][7]+"\n@\n"+(today.getDay+'/'+today.getMonth+'/'+today.getFullYear))
      ss.getRange(x+2,34).setValue()
      ss.getRange(x+2,35).setValue(data[x][35]+"\n@\n")
      ss.getRange(x+2,36).setValue(data[x][36]+"\n@\n")
      ss.getRange(x+2,37).setValue(data[x][37]+"\n@\n")
      ss.getRange(x+2,38).setValue(data[x][38]+"\n@\n")
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the Custom Function:

```
  function SLABANKING (start, startcongelamento, finalcongelamento, startdeclinio, finaldeclinio, cancelamento, end) {
  
  var today = new Date();
  var congelamento = 0
  var declinio = 0
  var x
  var y
  var z
  var s
  //typing error handling
  if (start == null || start == '') {
    return 'Necessário incluir data de início'
    } else if(startcongelamento.toString.length != finalcongelamento.toString.length && startcongelamento.toString.length - finalcongelamento.toString.length != 11) {
      return 'Erro de preenchimento de datas de congelamento'
    } else if(startdeclinio.toString.length != finaldeclinio.toString.length && startdeclinio.toString.length - finaldeclinio.toString.length != 11) {
      return 'Erro de preenchimento de datas de reabertura'
    } else {      
      //set de variáveis + complexas
      if(startcongelamento.toString().lastIndexOf('@') < 0) {
        var sconge = startcongelamento.toString().split('\n')
        var fconge = finalcongelamento.toString().split('\n')
        var sdec = startdeclinio.toString().split('\n')
        var fdec = finaldeclinio.toString().split('\n')
      } else {
        var sconge = startcongelamento.toString().slice(startcongelamento.toString().lastIndexOf('@')+2, startcongelamento.length).split('\n')
        var fconge = finalcongelamento.toString().slice(finalcongelamento.toString().lastIndexOf('@')+2, finalcongelamento.length).split('\n')
        var sdec = startdeclinio.toString().slice(startdeclinio.toString().lastIndexOf('@')+2, startdeclinio.length).split('\n')
        var fdec = finaldeclinio.toString().slice(finaldeclinio.toString().lastIndexOf('@')+2, finaldeclinio.length).split('\n')
      }
      //congelamento
      if(startcongelamento == null || startcongelamento == undefined || startcongelamento == ''){
      } else if(startcongelamento.length != finalcongelamento.length) {
        if (startcongelamento.length > 10 && finalcongelamento.length > 10) {
          Logger.log('desigual, start e final > 10')
          var display = []
          for (x = 0; x < sconge.length; x++) {
            if (x == sconge.length-1) {
              display.push(Math.floor(((Date.parse(today) - new Date(sconge[x].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7)))
            } else {
              display.push((new Date(fconge[x].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+fconge[x].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+fconge[x].toString().slice(6,10)) - new Date(sconge[x].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7)
            }
          }
          for (y = 0; y < display.length; y++) {
            congelamento = Number(congelamento) + Number(display[y])
          }
          return Math.ceil(congelamento)
        } else if (startcongelamento.length > 10) {
          Logger.log('desigual, só start > 10')
          var display = []
          for (x = 0; x < sconge.length; x++) {
            if (x == sconge.length-1) {
              display.push(Math.floor(((Date.parse(today) - new Date(sconge[x].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7)))
            } else {
              display.push((new Date(fconge) - new Date(sconge[x].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7)
            }
          }
          for (y = 0; y < display.length; y++) {
            congelamento = Number(congelamento) + Number(display[y])
          }
          return Math.ceil(congelamento)
        } else {
          Logger.log('desigual, nenhum > 10')
          congelamento = Math.floor(((Date.parse(today) - new Date(sconge))/8.64E7))
          return Math.ceil(congelamento)
        }
      } else {
        if (startcongelamento.length > 10) {
          Logger.log('igual, start e final > 10')
          for (x = 0; x < sconge.length; x++) {
            congelamento = congelamento + (new Date(fconge[x].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+fconge[x].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+fconge[x].toString().slice(6,10)) - new Date(sconge[x].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+sconge[x].toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7
          }
        } else {
          Logger.log('igual, nenhum > 10')
          congelamento = (new Date(fconge) - new Date(sconge))/8.64E7
        }
      }
      //declinio
      if (startdeclinio == null || startdeclinio == undefined || startdeclinio == ''){
      } else {
        if (startdeclinio.length > 10) {
          Logger.log('declinio, >10')
          for (y = 0; y < sdec.length; y++) {
            declinio = declinio + (new Date(fdec[y].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+fdec[y].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+fdec[y].toString().slice(6,10)) - new Date(sdec[y].toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+sdec[y].toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+sdec[y].toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7
          }
        } else {
          Logger.log('declinio, <10')
          declinio = (new Date(fdec) - new Date(sdec))/8.64E7
        }
      }

      if (start.length > 10) {
        var nstart = start.toString().slice(start.toString().lastIndexOf('@')+2, start.length)
        if(cancelamento != null && cancelamento != '') {
          return ((((new Date(cancelamento) - new Date(nstart.toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+nstart.toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+nstart.toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7 - congelamento) - declinio))
        } else if(end != null && end != '') {
          return ((((new Date(end) - new Date(nstart.toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+nstart.toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+nstart.toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7 - congelamento) - declinio))
        } else {
          return ((Math.floor((Date.parse(today) - new Date(nstart.toString().slice(3,5)+'/'+nstart.toString().slice(0,2)+'/'+nstart.toString().slice(6,10)))/8.64E7) - congelamento) - declinio)
        }
      } else {
        var nstart = start
        if(cancelamento != null && cancelamento != '') {
          return ((((new Date(cancelamento) - new Date(start))/8.64E7 - congelamento) - declinio))
        } else if(end != null && end != '') {
          return ((((new Date(end) - new Date(start))/8.64E7 - congelamento) - declinio))
        } else {
          return ((Math.floor((Date.parse(today) - new Date(start))/8.64E7) - congelamento) - declinio)
        }
      }     
    }
  }
```

Comment: `.getValues` is not being called. Is this on purpose?

Answer (score -1):

So, I got what I was doing wrong. Thanks evolutionxbox, btw, because you sparked my creativity.

I was not actually calling the methods. When the syntax was changed, the code worked.

Don't know if it was a fluke on my part, or if the autocomplete parameters changed, but, regardless, yes, methods must be called and parameters mustn't. :P

Comment: You confuse yourself with other programming languages. In google-apps-script you always use parenthesis when you call a method.